# Backend Settings not displayed on new instal of OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

This is my first install of **OctoberCMS** using the [Getting Started v2 Blog Post](http://octobercms.com). All worked as expected up to the point when I selected the Settings link in `/backend/system/settings`.

**Dashboard** is OK, **CMS** is OK, **Media** is also OK, but when I select **Settings**, the **LHS panel** is all grey. One thing I did notice is that the **Settings** do flash up on a reload, but are then obscured by the grey panel on the **LHS** of the page.

I am running MAMP on Mac with PHP 7.0.32 selected.
For what it is worth, the frontend pages appear to work OK.

Comment: - is your use is admin/super-admin and have proper rights?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is a fresh install and I assume that I have full admin rights. Is there a catch somewhere that I have missed ?

Comment: DUH! - Finger trouble. I had entered a search term in the search bar which when removed cleared the issue. If I try that again with the Settings view, I get the same thing. Looks like an issue to me! - Thanks anyway for your tip.